# How to crosstab a pandas dataframe when one variable (column) is a list of varying length

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

How can I generate a crossed table from the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=',')
dat.head(6)

  Factor1 Factor2
0       A       X
1       B       X
2       A     X|Y
3       B     X|Y
4       A   X|Y|Z
5       B   X|Y|Z

dat[['Factor2']] = dat[['Factor2']].applymap(lambda x : x.split('|'))
dat.head(6)

  Factor1    Factor2
0       A        [X]
1       B        [X]
2       A     [X, Y]
3       B     [X, Y]
4       A  [X, Y, Z]
5       B  [X, Y, Z]
```

The resulting `pd.crosstab()` should look like this:

```
  X Y Z
A 3 2 1
B 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to convert the `Feature2` column to indicator variables, then group the indicator variables by `Feature1` and aggregate with `sum`

```
df['Factor2'].str.get_dummies('|').groupby(df['Factor1']).sum()
```

---

```
         X  Y  Z
Factor1         
A        3  2  1
B        3  2  1
```

Answer (score 5):

You would have to first split on `|` using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then explode using [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
df['Factor2'] = df['Factor2'].str.split('|')
t = df.explode('Factor2')
pd.crosstab(t['Factor1'], t['Factor2'])

# Factor2  X  Y  Z
# Factor1         
# A        3  2  1
# B        3  2  1

# to remove the axis names.
# pd.crosstab(t['Factor1'], t['Factor2']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```